# What is the difference between a recusal and abstaining?

Tags: terminology, judiciary

Are these words synonyms or do they mean different things? A member of congress abstains from voting, while a judge recuses himself from a case. Is there a meaningful difference between the two out of political point-of-view?

I seem to want to think recusal is forced while abstaining is a choice, but I not certain if that is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Recusal** is when an official (either forced or voluntary) is removed entirely from proceedings - usually due to a conflict of interest.  It's a policy statement equivalent to "[person] shouldn't even be involved in any of this."

**Abstention**, on the other hand, is the decision of someone who *is* involved in the proceedings, to not make a determination about a given question, in either direction. Usually used by legislators who either don't care about how a question is decided, or don't want to be part of whatever majority does decide the issue - usually for political concerns; sometimes as a "I don't want this thing, but I'm not going to stand in the way of it happening if other people do."

The former is about ethics, questions of 'should.'  It's not always forced in fact, but the idea of someone voluntarily recusing themselves is that they are acknowledging a sort of 'being forced by morality.'

The latter is a matter of personal discretion.